# Python pandas: How to select the first not "None" value from a specif column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like fill a specif column of a dataset with the first not None value. For example, given the df:

```
col_name
None
None
A
A
B
B
```

output should be:

```
col_name
A
A
A
A
B
B
```

Any help on this, would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Carlo

Comment: What about `df.col_name.bfill()`?

Comment: I tried and does not work...it makes all the col_name with None value.

Comment: `df.col_name.apply(lambda x: numpy.nan if x==None else x)` then do bfill

Comment: how can I add inplace=True? to the df.col_name.bfill()

Comment: no, it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.update(df.col_name.iloc[:df.col_name.notnull().argmax() + 1].bfill())

df

  col_name
0        A
1        A
2        A
3        A
4        B
5        B
```

---

Same Idea, but different

```
i = df.col_name.notnull().argmax()
df.col_name.values[:i] = df.col_name.values[i]
```

---

If `None` values are actually strings as in `'None'`

```
i = df.col_name.ne('None').argmax()
df.col_name.iloc[:i] = df.col_name.iloc[i]
```

Comment: how can I add  inplace=True to your suggestion? Many Thanks,

Comment: I see. I am running it...just a sec

Comment: The first suggestion does not work for me. I try the other one.

Comment: I got the following error: IndexError: index 173 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 109

Comment: Are you sure those are `None` and not `'None'`.  Can you run `df.col_name.apply(type).iloc[:3]` and report back what you get.

Comment: @CarloAllocca this works for me with your sample data.  If it doesn't work for you, then it is likely your data.  I cannot help you without you sharing more information about the data.  How you are importing it, `dtypes`, etc.

Comment: Please, I am checking it as you suggesting. One minute and I report it back

Comment: @CarloAllocca also, that error `index 173 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 109 ` is impossible to get with my code.

Comment: this error is because I am using a different data sample.

Comment: Ok. you are right. when I run  df.col_name.apply(type).iloc[:3],                  type 2020    <class 'str'>
1641    <class 'str'>
2021    <class 'str'>
Name: Operation_progress, dtype: object

Comment: @CarloAllocca I want to help.  I'll be here.  I just wanted to make it clear, this has transcended from being a question about how to logically accomplish your task to a question about how to clean your data.  I can help clean your data but I need more information.

Comment: Many Thank for your provided help so far.

Comment: it seems to be string and not None. How should I change yours solution? Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to leave it string?  I'll add a solution for that.

Comment: Yes, if it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: Many Thanks piRSquared. Thanks to your suggestion I did it.

Comment: The full solution is to add df["col_name"].replace('None',np.nan, inplace=True) and then your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to a numpy array by the dataframe.values variable, and then loop through it, comparing to numpy.nan, setting the value when true

eg.

colName = df['col_name'].values

colName[numpy.isnan(colName)] = 'A'